# I want the count of records with no values existing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these result attached and all I want is that days & hours and records of days that there is no count.

Thanks below is the query I used

```
SELECT dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, date_sent_to_adobe), 0) as TimeStampHour, Count(*) 'Total Count this Hour'
FROM [Publication_Data_Management].[AdobeExtract].[Membership_Detail]
GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, date_sent_to_adobe), 0)
ORDER BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, date_sent_to_adobe), 0) desc
```

is it because the way the query is written it will only show dates in the table , how can I rewrite the query to show days with every hours where there is no count of records. see the attached picture.
[image]

Comment: I am using sql server 2014

Comment: Create a help calendar table with all possible values. Right join with that table.

Comment: Just to pile onto @jarlh's comment, this is what's known as an "islands and gaps" problem and in this case a calendar table (which is immensely useful in its own right) will help you solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate all the rows and then use `left join` and `group by` to bring in the rows.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour, h.hr, d.dte) as TimeStampHour,
       Count(*) as total_count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(date_sent_to_adobe as DATE) as dte
      FROM Publication_Data_Management.AdobeExtract.Membership_Detail
     ) d CROSS JOIN
     (VALUE (0), (1), (2), . . ., (23) ) as h(hr) LEFT JOIN
     Publication_Data_Management.AdobeExtract.Membership_Detail md
     ON md.date_sent_to_adobe >= DATEADD(hour, h.hr, d.dte) AND
        md.date_sent_to_adobe < DATEADD(hour, h.hr + 1, d.dte)
GROUP BY DATEADD(hour, h.hr, d.dte)
ORDER BY DATEADD(hour, h.hr, d.dte) DESC;
```